# How to remove this Warning in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

**warning** cannot modify header information - headers already sent by in wordpress

**Warning**: `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/arnell75/public_html/makemoneyonlinein1day.com/arc-arnell/wp-content/plugins/facebook-like-box-widget/facebook-like-box-widget.php:1) in /home1/arnell75/public_html/makemoneyonlinein1day.com/arc-arnell/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876`

Comment: Have you tried these steps? http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F

Comment: "makemoneyonlinein1day.com"? Can't you afford to hire someone to help out? But seriously, looks like the Facebook Like Box Widget plugin might be causing the problem. First thing I'd probably try is disabling it and seeing if the problem goes away. If it does, maybe try deleting it and re-installing it..

Answer (score 0):

The php ["header"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function will run only if no output was rendered to the client side else it will return an warning. This error is usually caused by an empty row or a space character in the begging of the file before the '< ?php' tag.

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify any file, just revert it back if you can. Chances are there is some line/space in functions.php outside php tags.